# Accessing only rows in DataFrame where the content of one column intersects with other set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

as so often I am confused by how dataframes are accessed.
I have a dataframe (lets call it df) like this:

| id_one | id_two | sets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | {234, 345, 546, ...} |
| 2 | -234 | {123, 234, 645, ...} |
| ... | ... | ... |

... 25 Million rows worth of this.

I want to filter the dataframe and only show rows where the set in "sets" intersects with another set, lets call it reference_set = {542345, 423, 64564, 435, ...etc}. Later I want to quantify this intersection, that's why I need the length of the intersection.

This does not work:

```
df.loc[
    len(
        df['sets'].intersection(reference_set) 
    ) > 0]
```

It gives "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'intersection'"

Shouldn't it give a Boolean list to select on? Am I not following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values) correctly?

Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to obtain the intersection between the reference set and the set on each row of the dataframe. Then, apply the `len` function over the newly created column (`Intersect`) to quantify each intersection. This will enable you to filter the dataframe and only show rows where the set in `sets` intersects with another set (`df['Len'] > 0`).

**df** used as input

```py
   id_one  id_two                                                                                         sets
0    7575     527          {1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 13, 16, 20, 24, 31, 40, 47, 50, 52, 57, 61, 64, 69, 80, 88, 91, 96}
1     574    1555      {7, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 30, 39, 43, 47, 50, 58, 62, 64, 72, 76, 77, 83, 84, 86, 87, 96}
2    7831    8823  {5, 14, 15, 20, 23, 28, 30, 32, 35, 36, 40, 41, 44, 52, 54, 59, 60, 62, 63, 84, 87, 90, 96}
3     688    6860           {2, 9, 20, 24, 27, 28, 30, 38, 46, 57, 59, 60, 64, 65, 69, 71, 80, 84, 88, 91, 95}
4    8843     596    {6, 7, 8, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 47, 50, 54, 56, 57, 61, 64, 66, 69, 74, 78, 81, 85, 88, 99}
5    1269    7546             {11, 22, 24, 25, 33, 35, 45, 48, 49, 54, 57, 59, 61, 68, 70, 75, 86, 87, 94, 95}
6    1362    4860           {2, 5, 14, 19, 23, 32, 37, 38, 47, 48, 58, 62, 65, 68, 70, 72, 73, 77, 82, 88, 91}
7    7994    7192      {2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 20, 24, 25, 29, 40, 50, 57, 64, 71, 78, 89, 95, 99}
8     748    6271  {1, 12, 19, 26, 30, 34, 45, 48, 52, 60, 67, 72, 73, 74, 76, 80, 82, 84, 89, 94, 96, 98, 99}
9     553    4068  {9, 12, 15, 20, 35, 39, 40, 41, 44, 45, 50, 57, 65, 67, 68, 69, 72, 73, 79, 87, 88, 97, 98}
```

```py
REFERENCE_SET = {10, 18, 23, 55, 90, 92}

df['Intersect'] = df['sets'].apply(lambda row: REFERENCE_SET.intersection(row))
df['Len'] = df['Intersect'].apply(len)

df_filtered = df[df['Len'] > 0]
```

Output from **df_filtered**

```py
   id_one  id_two                                                                                         sets Intersect  Len
1     574    1555      {7, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 30, 39, 43, 47, 50, 58, 62, 64, 72, 76, 77, 83, 84, 86, 87, 96}  {18, 23}    2
2    7831    8823  {5, 14, 15, 20, 23, 28, 30, 32, 35, 36, 40, 41, 44, 52, 54, 59, 60, 62, 63, 84, 87, 90, 96}  {90, 23}    2
6    1362    4860           {2, 5, 14, 19, 23, 32, 37, 38, 47, 48, 58, 62, 65, 68, 70, 72, 73, 77, 82, 88, 91}      {23}    1
```